# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1385.collectToPython

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I am trying to pred = ann_result.select(['prediction']).collect()

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import MultilayerPerceptronClassifier
layers = [20, 2, 2, 9]
# create the trainer and set its parameters
ann = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(featuresCol='features',labelCol='Sub_Cat',maxIter=100, 
layers=layers, blockSize=128, seed=1234)
assemblerann = VectorAssembler(inputCols =['a','b','c','Sub_Cat'],
                        outputCol='features')
pipelineann = Pipeline(stages = [assemblerann,ann])
ann_model = pipelineann.fit(train_data)
ann_result = ann_model.transform(test_data)
```

i'm getting following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1385.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 420.0 
failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 420.0 (TID 1684) (DESKTOP-GE42B2K 
executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined 
function(ProbabilisticClassificationModel$$Lambda$3368/227548575: 
(struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>) => 
struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
 at 


org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source
```

)

Comment: How was it resolved at last?